# Getting values in my Java class from velocity (Jira plugin webwork module )

Tags: jira, velocity, webwork

I am creating a Jira plugin which provides a version tab panel. In the velocity of this version tab panel i am providing a select list . the code of select list is as below

```
                    <form name="input" action="AddParent" method="post">
        <select name="parentVersion">
        <option value="-1">--select Parent--</option>
        #foreach($version in $versions )
            <option value="$version" selected="true">$version</option>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Parent"/>
        </form>
```

Now in my plugin i have included a webwork module to handle this action . when i click the "Add Parent" button nothing is happening. I need the value which i have selected in my java action class . I am surely missing something . can someone please help me with this ?
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what's missing in your code, but the WebWork Sample Plugin has more information about this.

Comment: Hi Matt ,i referred Webwork sample and was able to get the values by using the request.getParameter("parentVersion") method i made these changes in the velocity template <form name="input" action="${baseurl}/secure/AddParent.jspa" method="post"> . The tutorials helped alot . Thanx :)

Comment: @mdoar: Could you link to that WebWork Sample Plugin?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can declare a local variable named same as your select list, create getter and setter and the variable will get the selected value.
Also, yo can specify the form action as `action="YourClass!yourMethod.jspa"`

```
private String parentVersion;

public String getParentVersion() {
    return parentVersion;
}
public void setParentVersion(String parentVersion) {
    this.parentVersion = parentVersion;
}
```